# Meta-analysis with metafor package: Strange difference between rma and rma.mv

Tags: r

I am working on a meta regression using the metafor package. My simple trial estimation is:

```
m1<-rma(yi=COEFF, sei=STDERR, mods = ~ MT_TIMESERIES + MT_BIVARIATE, method="REML", data=y)
```

Next I estimate the same model with rma.mv() and use a random term RID which is a factor identifying each single observation (no clusters of observations):

```
m2<-rma.mv(yi=COEFF, V=STDERR^2, random= ~ 1|RID, mods = ~ MT_TIMESERIES + MT_BIVARIATE, method="REML", data=y)
```

Estimations m1 and m2 should actually yield the same results (this idea is supported by a note from the package author on http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:rma.uni_vs_rma.mv).

But in fact, they don't:

```
> summary(m1)

Mixed-Effects Model (k = 886; tau^2 estimator: REML)

logLik    deviance         AIC         BIC        AICc  
-4847.7988   9695.5976   9703.5976   9722.7309   9703.6431  

tau^2 (estimated amount of residual heterogeneity):     0.0000 (SE = 0.0000)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):             0.0007
I^2 (residual heterogeneity / unaccounted variability): 1.21%
H^2 (unaccounted variability / sampling variability):   1.01
R^2 (amount of heterogeneity accounted for):            87.37%

Test for Residual Heterogeneity: 
QE(df = 883) = 9083.3858, p-val < .0001

Test of Moderators (coefficient(s) 2,3): 
QM(df = 2) = 104.7561, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

               estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub     
intrcpt         -0.0076  0.0009  -8.6343  <.0001  -0.0093  -0.0059  ***
MT_TIMESERIES    0.0004  0.0010   0.3669  0.7137  -0.0016   0.0023     
MT_BIVARIATE     0.0062  0.0010   6.4595  <.0001   0.0043   0.0081  ***

> summary(m2)

Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 886; method: REML)

logLik    Deviance         AIC         BIC        AICc  
-2948.3789   5896.7578   5904.7578   5923.8911   5904.8034  

Variance Components: 

            estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed  factor
sigma^2    3.2560  1.8044    886     no     RID

Test for Residual Heterogeneity: 
QE(df = 883) = 9083.3858, p-val < .0001

Test of Moderators (coefficient(s) 2,3): 
QM(df = 2) = 13.7838, p-val = 0.0010

Model Results:

               estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub     
intrcpt         -0.5362  0.1262  -4.2475  <.0001  -0.7836  -0.2888  ***
MT_TIMESERIES   -0.5021  0.1557  -3.2237  0.0013  -0.8073  -0.1968   **
MT_BIVARIATE    -0.5016  0.1949  -2.5742  0.0100  -0.8835  -0.1197    *
```

Does anyone have an idea why that could be?

Many thanks in advance!

Best regards

Joachim

Comment: This is indeed peculiar. But I have a hunch what might be going on. Could you create and ideally post the likelihood profile plot for one of these models with a range that encompasses both estimates of the variance component? That is: ``profile(m1, xlim=c(0,5), steps=50)`` (or ``profile(m2, sigma2=1, xlim=c(0,5), steps=50)`` but that should look the same). This may take a couple minutes to complete, so please be patient while this runs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The likelihood profiles look indeed the same. [m1](http://www.zuckarelli.de/Rplot_m1.jpeg) and [m2](http://www.zuckarelli.de/Rplot_m2.jpeg)

Comment: Hmmm, very strange. The likelihood profile is almost flat beyond a value of ~2 but for smaller values it does drop off and especially close to 0. Sorry, since I don't have the data, I just have to ask: What does ``profile(m1,  xlim=c(0,.1))`` look like? Or play around with ``xlim`` a bit. Maybe there is a local maximum close to 0.

Comment: I have tried several xlims, but I can't find a local maximum. Some examples here: [example1](http://www.zuckarelli.de/Rplot_m1_1.jpg), [example2](http://www.zuckarelli.de/Rplot_m1_2.jpg), [example3](http://www.zuckarelli.de/Rplot_m1_3.jpg).

Comment: Thank you. Even stranger now. For some reason, ``rma()`` is not finding the peak. What do you get if you fit with ``rma(..., verbose=TRUE)``? Is it immediately getting stuck at the value close to 0? I recently wrote up an extensive discussion of the Fisher scoring algorithm underlying the ``rma()`` function (http://metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:convergence_problems_rma), but the issues discussed there are a bit different, as it is converging, but to the wrong value. Could you contact me directly? If possible, I would like to play around with the data myself.

Comment: @Wolfgang Was this problem ever resolved? What happened?

Comment: @Speldosa No, unfortunately, the OP never got in touch with me. Without the data or some reproducible example, I can only speculate what the nature of the issue is.